# Flutter - click an image and an overlay image will appear below

Tags: flutter, image, overlay

I'm new to StackOverflow and flutter and trying to write a mobile app. Maybe it is a simple problem, but I don't know how to do it. I tried to do it many times just to appear the overlay image but no images is appearing.

My target is 3 icon, which can also appear as three individual images below them.

I really need help, please.

```
    [@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
                body: Container(
                    width: size.width,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Container(
                            height: size.height,
                            width: size.width,
                            decoration:
                                BoxDecoration(color: ColorConstant.whiteA700),
                            child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.topCenter, children: \[
                              Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                      ImageConstant.imgAchievementsbg,
                                      height: getVerticalSize(800.00),
                                      width: getHorizontalSize(360.00),
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                              Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                  child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: getHorizontalSize(18.00),
                                          top: getVerticalSize(9.00),
                                          right: getHorizontalSize(18.00),
                                          bottom: getVerticalSize(10.00)),
                                      child: Column(
                                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: \[
                                            GestureDetector(
                                                onTap: () {
                                                  onTapImgBackbutton4();
                                                },
                                                child: Padding(
                                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                        left: getHorizontalSize(
                                                            10.00)),
                                                    child: Image.asset(
                                                        ImageConstant
                                                            .imgBackbutton4,
                                                        height: getSize(38.00),
                                                        width: getSize(38.00),
                                                        fit: BoxFit.fill))),
                                            Align(
                                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                                child: Padding(
                                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                        top:
                                                            getVerticalSize(75.00)),
                                                    child: Row(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                                            MainAxisAlignment
                                                                .spaceBetween,
                                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                                            CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                                        mainAxisSize:
                                                            MainAxisSize.max,
                                                        children: \[
                                                          Padding(
                                                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                  bottom:
                                                                      getVerticalSize(
                                                                          2.00)),
                                                              child: Column(
                                                                  mainAxisSize:
                                                                      MainAxisSize
                                                                          .min,
                                                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                      CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                          .start,
                                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                                          .start,
                                                                  children: \[
                                                                    Align(
                                                                        alignment:
                                                                            Alignment
                                                                                .center,
                                                                        child: Padding(
                                                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                                right: getHorizontalSize(
                                                                                    2.00)),
                                                                            child: Text(
                                                                                "msg_click_on_an_ico"
                                                                                    .tr,
                                                                                overflow:
                                                                                    TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                                                style: AppStyle.textstylehywenheihew15.copyWith(fontSize: getFontSize(15), height: 2.13)))),
    
                                                                    //START OF ICONS
                                                                    Container(
                                                                        width: getHorizontalSize(
                                                                            194.00),
                                                                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                            top: getVerticalSize(
                                                                                44.00)),
                                                                        child: Row(
                                                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                                                MainAxisAlignment
                                                                                    .spaceBetween,
                                                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                                CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                                    .center,
                                                                            mainAxisSize:
                                                                                MainAxisSize.max,
                                                                                
                                                                            children: \[
                                                                              Image.asset(
                                                                                  ImageConstant.imgJavaicon,
                                                                                  height: getVerticalSize(98.00),
                                                                                  width: getHorizontalSize(78.00),
                                                                                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
                                                                              Image.asset(
                                                                                  ImageConstant.imgPhpicon,
                                                                                  height: getVerticalSize(98.00),
                                                                                  width: getHorizontalSize(80.00),
                                                                                  fit: BoxFit.fill)
                                                                            \]))
                                                                  \])),
                                                          Padding(
                                                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                  top:
                                                                      getVerticalSize(
                                                                          76.00),
                                                                  right:
                                                                      getHorizontalSize(
                                                                          7.00)),
                                                              child: Image.asset(
                                                                  ImageConstant
                                                                      .imgCppicon,
                                                                  height:
                                                                      getVerticalSize(
                                                                          100.00),
                                                                  width:
                                                                      getHorizontalSize(
                                                                          80.00),
                                                                  fit: BoxFit.fill))
                                                        \])))
                                          \])))
                            \]))))));
      }
    
      onTapImgBackbutton4() {
        Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.frontPageScreen);
      }
    }

I also tried this Gesture Detector but the overlay image is not appearing.

class AchivementPageScreen extends GetWidget<AchivementPageController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
            body: Container(
                width: size.width,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Container(
                        height: size.height,
                        width: size.width,
                        decoration:
                            BoxDecoration(color: ColorConstant.whiteA700),
                        child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.topCenter, children: [
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Image.asset(
                                  ImageConstant.imgAchievementsbg,
                                  height: getVerticalSize(800.00),
                                  width: getHorizontalSize(360.00),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                              child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: getHorizontalSize(18.00),
                                      top: getVerticalSize(9.00),
                                      right: getHorizontalSize(18.00),
                                      bottom: getVerticalSize(10.00)),
                                  child: Column(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              onTapImgBackbutton4();
                                            },
                                            child: Padding(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    left: getHorizontalSize(
                                                        10.00)),
                                                child: Image.asset(
                                                    ImageConstant
                                                        .imgBackbutton4,
                                                    height: getSize(38.00),
                                                    width: getSize(38.00),
                                                    fit: BoxFit.fill))),
                                        Align(
                                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                            child: Padding(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    top:
                                                        getVerticalSize(75.00)),
                                                child: Row(
                                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                                        MainAxisAlignment
                                                            .spaceBetween,
                                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                                        CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                                    mainAxisSize:
                                                        MainAxisSize.max,
                                                    children: [
                                                      Padding(
                                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                              bottom:
                                                                  getVerticalSize(
                                                                      2.00)),
                                                          child: Column(
                                                              mainAxisSize:
                                                                  MainAxisSize
                                                                      .min,
                                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                  CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                      .start,
                                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                                  MainAxisAlignment
                                                                      .start,
                                                              children: [
                                                                Align(
                                                                    alignment:
                                                                        Alignment
                                                                            .center,
                                                                    child: Padding(
                                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                            right: getHorizontalSize(
                                                                                2.00)),
                                                                        child: Text(
                                                                            "msg_click_on_an_ico"
                                                                                .tr,
                                                                            overflow:
                                                                                TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                                            style: AppStyle.textstylehywenheihew15.copyWith(fontSize: getFontSize(15), height: 2.13)))),

                                                                //START OF ICONS
                                                                Align(
                                                                    alignment:
                                                                        Alignment
                                                                            .topCenter,
                                                                    child: Padding(
                                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: getHorizontalSize(2.00), top: getVerticalSize(44.00), right: getHorizontalSize(28.00), bottom: getVerticalSize(225.00)),
                                                                        child: Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: [
                                                                          GestureDetector(
                                                                              onTap: () {
                                                                                onTapImgJavaicon();
                                                                              },
                                                                              child: Image.asset(ImageConstant.imgJavaicon, height: getVerticalSize(98.00), width: getHorizontalSize(80.00), fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                                                                          GestureDetector(
                                                                              onTap: () {
                                                                                onTapImgPhpicon();
                                                                              },
                                                                              child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: getHorizontalSize(26.00)), child: Image.asset(ImageConstant.imgPhpicon, height: getVerticalSize(98.00), width: getHorizontalSize(80.00), fit: BoxFit.fill))),
                                                                          GestureDetector(
                                                                              onTap: () {
                                                                                onTapImgCppicon();
                                                                              },
                                                                              child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: getHorizontalSize(26.00)), child: Image.asset(ImageConstant.imgCppicon, height: getVerticalSize(98.00), width: getHorizontalSize(80.00), fit: BoxFit.fill)))
                                                                        ])))
                                                              ]))
                                                    ])))
                                      ])))
                        ]))))));
  }

  onTapImgBackbutton4() {
    Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.frontPageScreen);
  }
}

onTapImgCppicon() {}

onTapImgPhpicon() {}

onTapImgJavaicon() {
  child:
  Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: ExactAssetImage('assets/img_Java.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
  );
}
```

[Design reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBsSS.jpg)

Comment: is there any design references for your requirement?

Comment: yes, I edited my question to add the image of the page I am working with

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Row.

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: yourImageWidget,
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: yourImageWidget,
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: yourImageWidget,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```